# zClip jQuery plugin isn't copying the new value of text inputs

Tags: jquery, input, zclip

In my CakePHP application, I have a view with this markup:

```
<div class="copy" id="share-copy"></div>
<input type="text" value="http://site.com/v/<?php echo $imageInfo[0]['Image']['hash']; ?>" name="share" />
```

The `share-copy` DIV is a little 16x16 div that houses the flash element for zClip. I'm using zClip like this:

```
$('#share-copy').zclip({
    path: '/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: $('input[name="share"]').val(),
    afterCopy: function(){}
});
```

Now, it successfully copies the text in the input element named `share`. However, when I change the text in that input element using jQuery like this:

```
$('input[name="share"]').attr('value', 'something');
```

and click zClip again, it doesn't copy the new value. How can I get zClip to copy exactly what's inside the `share` input at the time of clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

```
$('#share-copy').zclip({
    path: '/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: $('input[name="share"]').val(),
    afterCopy: function(){}
});
```

creates an object:

```
{path: '/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf', copy: $('input[name="share"]').val(), afterCopy: function(){}}
```

And the value of property `copy` is set when the object is created, so it doesn't update.

I guess we can solve it using a function:

```
$('#share-copy').zclip({
    path: '/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function(){return $('input[name="share"]').val();},
    afterCopy: function(){}
});
```